# OxyPlot HeatMapSeries Origin Start from top left instead

Tags: oxyplot

For the 2D array passed in as `Data` for `HeatMapSeries` of the OxyPlot library, the 2D array with [0,0] starts at the bottom left corner.

How do I go about manipulating the data/the `HeatMapSeries` in order to make the [0,0] data start from the top left corner instead?